# F# assigning inherited property values in inherited constructors parameter list

Tags: f#

I can't give an explanation to this error (F# 4.1 in VS 2017).

Common code:

```
open Eto.Forms

type MyCommand() as this = 
    inherit Eto.Forms.Command()
    do
        this.MenuText <- "C&lick Me, Command"
        this.ToolBarText <- "Click Me"
        this.ToolTip <- "This shows a dialog for no reason"
        this.Shortcut <- Application.Instance.CommonModifier ||| Keys.M
```

The following declaration is not accepted by the F# editor; the error message detected in the Menu initialization is "Named arguments must appear after all other arguments":

```
type MyForm1() =
    inherit Eto.Forms.Form(
        Title = "Eto Tests"
        , ClientSize = Eto.Drawing.Size(600, 400)
        , Menu = seq {yield new MyCommand()} |> Seq.fold (fun (mb:MenuBar) c -> mb.Items.Add(c) |> ignore; mb) (new MenuBar())
     )
```

The following declaration works without errors instead:

```
type MyForm1() =
    inherit Eto.Forms.Form(
        Title = "Eto Tests"
        , ClientSize = Eto.Drawing.Size(600, 400)
        , Menu = let m = seq {yield new MyCommand()} |> Seq.fold (fun (mb:MenuBar) c -> mb.Items.Add(c) |> ignore; mb) (new MenuBar()) in m
     )
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks like the ``let m = … in …`` construct works like a pair of parentheses here. Try using ``Menu = (seq { yield … (new MenuBar ()))`` in your code.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like certain characters in the parameter value stump the parser and it parses the whole thing as a comparison (i.e. `x = y`), and since that's a boolean value, it assumes that it must be value of an unnamed parameter, hence the error.

I couldn't find any mentions of this in the F# spec, but my experiments so far have revealed that the list of offending characters includes (but is not limited to) `<`, `>`, `$`, and `&`. The plus sign `+` and curly braces `{ }` are not in the list.

```
type T = T with static member M(x: int, y: bool, z: int seq) = ()
let inline ($) a b = a + b

T.M(
    y = true, z = [],
    x = 5 $ 4 // Fails
)

T.M(
    y = true, z = [],
    x = 5 + 4 // Works
)

T.M(
    y = true, x = 5,
    z = seq { yield 5 }  // Works
)

T.M(
    y = true, z = [],
    x = seq { yield 5 } |> Seq.head  // Fails due to the `>` symbol in the pipe
)


T.M(
    x = 5, z = [],
    y = 4 < 3  // Fails
)

T.M(
    x = 5, z = [],
    y = true & false  // Fails
)
```

Fortunately, there is a workaround: enclose the whole value in a pair of parentheses. That helps the parser correctly determine where the value is.